# How to create delegate generic with param optional?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I try to create a function that get name of function - delegate that get optional generic parameter.

The purpose of my function is to: Listen to a folder, which when files come with certain names - will activate a certain function.
I searched and found that the only choice is to write code twice.
I don't want to write code twice, does anyone have an idea how to do it better?

The code:

```
public delegate void ActionFound<T>(T param);
public delegate void ActionNotFound<T>(T param);

public class FileListenerHelper
{

    public static void FileListener<T>(string folder, List<string> filesName, int waitingMinutes, ActionFound<T> found, T param, ActionNotFound<T> notFound = null)
    {
        if (filesName.SelectMany(f => Directory.GetFiles(folder, f + "*")).IsNotNullOrEmpty())
        {
            found(param);
            return;
        }
        bool ifNotRun = true;
        bool isStillRun = false;
        var completedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = folder,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName
        };

        watcher.Created += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (filesName.SelectMany(f => Directory.GetFiles(folder, f + "*")).IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                isStillRun = true;
                ifNotRun = false;
                completedEvent.Set();
                found(param);
                isStillRun = false;
            }
        };
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


        var startDate = DateTime.Now;
        var endDate = startDate.AddMinutes(waitingMinutes);
        var mi = HighResClock.CalcTimeSpan(startDate, endDate).TotalMilliseconds.ToInt();
        completedEvent.WaitOne(mi);

        while (isStillRun)
        {

        }

        if (ifNotRun && notFound.IsNotNull())
        {
            notFound(param);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fix it, Sory...

Comment: If you need teh name of a function the two options are reflection and CallerMemberName, with the later bein preferable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If you want to listen to folder changes, the way is the FileSystemWatcher: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8 | Maybe you could use Hooks too, but I would not advise it considering you got a managed option.

Comment: I want my function, I think that's how I manage it better ...

Comment: I don't understand how to do it with `CallerMemberName`

Comment: @Ayala: You write a function and apply this atribute to a string argument. As long as no other value is given to the argument, the name of the caller will be used as automatic value.

Comment: Hoe can I exec the function with `CallerMemberName`??

Comment: `public void sayMyName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = ""){}` If you call this from your ``FileListenerFileListener Function, "FileListener" will be what is in member Name.

Comment: what that you wort me is how to get the name of the functio, yes? How can I execute the function that I get by string?

Comment: Every-one call to `FileListener`, and I don't know witch namespace the function that they want...

Comment: "How can I execute the function that I get by string?" That is not the question you asked thus far. You asked how to get the Name of a Function. Not how to execute a function by it's name. However the answer is still the same: Reflection. But you should really look if you even need this, because Reflection tends to be used when there is no reason for it.

Comment: So I have no Idea, How can I wort it better then write all the code duplicate?

Comment: For your stated requirement, this code makes no sense. To lsiten for files: You instantiate a file listener. Point it to the folder. Give it a event handler. And then handle the event, like you would in every GUI project. | That whole idea of "calling a function by it's name" is not required for any of this, so I have no idea what you even need it for.

Comment: So I can I handle the event?